# How to make all borders the same color?

Tags: css

I have a simple form, with text fields that I'm trying to have borders in the same color. For some reason the left and top borders appear in a slightly different color, which appear to be some kind of shadow. How do I get rid of it?

I'm using this (relevant) CSS to style the text fields:

```
input[type="text"] {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

I've also tried adding this piece of code, but with no luck:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `border-style:solid;`

```css
input[type="text"] {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

I believe "inset" is the default for many browsers for text inputs.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the default input styling applied by your browser, which sets the `border-style` to `inset`. You can get your desired styling, and simplify your CSS rule by changing your CSS to:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" />
```